# Searching for a particular value in a single linked list

Tags: c++, xcode, linked-list

I am trying to implement a generic single linked list. So far I have everything done correctly but I cannot get my search function to work properly. It should print "yes"in the output but nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef LinkedList_hpp
#define LinkedList_hpp

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node<T>* next;
};

template<class T>
class SingleLinkedList {
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;

public:
    SingleLinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    void createNode(const T& theData) {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        temp->data = theData;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        if(head == nullptr) {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr) {
            std::cout << temp->data << "\t";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void insert_start(const T& theData) {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        temp->data = theData;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    void insert_position(int pos, const T& theData) {
        Node<T>* previous = new Node<T>;
        Node<T>* current = new Node<T>;
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        current = head;
        for(int i  = 1; i < pos; i++) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        temp->data = theData;
        previous->next = temp;
        temp->next = current;
    }

    void delete_first() {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    void delete_last() {
        Node<T>* previous = new Node<T>;
        Node<T>* current = new Node<T>;
        current = head;
        while(current->next != nullptr) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        tail = previous;
        previous->next = nullptr;
        delete current;
    }

    void delete_position(int pos) {
        Node<T>* previous = new Node<T>;
        Node<T>* current = new Node<T>;
        current = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        previous->next = current->next;
    }

    bool search(Node<T>* head, int x) {
        struct Node<T>* current = head;  
        while (current != NULL) {
            if (current->data == x)
                return true;
            current = current->next;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

#endif /* LinkedList_hpp */
```

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    SingleLinkedList<int> obj;
    obj.createNode(2);
    obj.createNode(4);
    obj.createNode(6);
    obj.createNode(8);
    obj.createNode(10);
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Displaying All nodes---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-----------------Inserting At End-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.createNode(55);
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Inserting At Start----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insert_start(50);
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-------------Inserting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insert_position(5,60);
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At Start-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.delete_first();
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-----------------Deleing At End-------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.delete_last();
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"--------------Deleting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.delete_position(4);
    obj.display();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    system("pause");

    Node<int>* head = NULL;
    obj.search(head, 8) ? printf("Yes") : printf("No");


    return 0;
}
```

You can see that I search for the value 8 and it should print yes since 8 is still in the linked list.

Comment: `Node<int>* head = NULL;` ... is that the list you are searching?  That's an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `search` function:

```
bool search(Node<T>* head, int x) {
    struct Node<T>* current = head;  
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->data == x)
            return true;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It uses the argument `head` passed into as the first argument, instead of the `SingleLinkedList<T>::head` member variable.

And since you call it passing a null pointer as the first argument, you will not find anything.

Simple fix: Remove the first argument from the `search` function:

```
bool search(T x) { ... }
```

As you see I also changed the argument of the value you search for to the template type.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Node<int>* head = NULL;
```

mean you are passing NULL into your search method.

Your search method should not take a head parameter at all - `head` is already a member of your class.

Also note: you have lots of memory leaks like this:

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
temp = head;
```

You don't need to allocate memory for a pointer that you are just going to overwrite with a new value, just use

```
Node<T>* temp = head;
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed what you suggested. Is there any other memory leaks besides those?

Comment: In general, you normally want to make sure that your `new`s are paired up with `delete`s. For a linked list, you probably only want to do new on the create/insert type methods and delete in the delete type methods. That said - you currently don't `delete` the item in `delete_position`, and you also don't `delete` all the items in your destructor (as you don't have one).

Comment: Another couple of things to look at is that you don't use `tail` anywhere, and you are also not keeping it up to date in any of the `insert_*` or `delete_*` methods (except `delete_last`) it might be better not to have it. Also look up the "c++ rule of three" as currently your class is not safely copyable.

Comment: Thank you for your points. I created a destructor now but where do I call the delete? Could you reference a function where I would call delete?

Comment: Your destructor is called automatically when an object of your class is destroyed (e.g. `obj` is destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of main). At that time your should call `delete` on anything you have created using `new`, in this case that means deleting all elements in the list. Note that this does not cause an issue for your current program, as you are exiting the program anyway and all memory will be released back to the OS. But if you intend to use your class in a longer running program, you should always clean up your memory.